# How do I change target filename in nuget package when packing via msbuild pack target?

Tags: msbuild, nuget, csproj

I have a `csproj` file containing entry like

```
<None Include="library.txt" Pack="true" PackagePath="content" />
```

The file is correctly included in the nuget package as `/content/library.txt`.
Is there a way how to change the file name itself (the package path is always just directory). I.E. what I'm after is
`/content/readme.md` in nuget without changing the source file name or extension.

This is possible in vanilla nuget (for reference
[How do I change target filename in NuGet Package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23242137/how-do-i-change-target-filename-in-nuget-package))

Answer (score 2):

> This is possible in vanilla nuget

That is not true according to the linked post, if you look at the note at the bottom.

> The File extension in src and target must match or the specified target will be treated like a directory.

The same behavior **also applies** to `csproj`. As long as the file extension of your included file matches the output file it works. Using the following line would include the `library.txt` file as `readme.txt` in the package.

```
<None Include="library.txt" Pack="true" PackagePath="/content/readme.txt" />
```

However, if you would use a different file extension, e.g. `PackagePath="/content/readme.md"`, then the path in the package would be `/content/readme.md/library.txt`. See this [comment on an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/6351#issuecomment-478903940) from Jon Skeet. This issue still persists in Visual Studio 2019, too.

The easiest workaround is to rename the file to your target file name, obviously. Of course you can copy the file on build and pack it manually or employ MSBuild magic, but I do not think you can do this with `csproj` as of now.

Comment: Nice didn't know.